# Filtering IP packets that contain IP options using ACL

Tags: cisco, ip, cisco-ios

Is it smart to have ACE

```
#deny ip any any option any-options
```

enabled as part of hardening the router?

Is there some legitimate traffic that use IP options? Or should I use selective drop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it smart to drop IP options as part of hardening the router?

Yes, as long as you don't need them.  Most people don't need IPv4 Options.

> Is there some legitimate traffic that use IP options? Or should I use selective drop?

The most common usages for IP options are listed on [Cisco's site](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_0s/feature/guide/sel_drop.html#wp1043334): IGMPv2 and MPLS-TE with RSVP.

If you feel like reading a lot, [RFC 7126](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7126) offers a pretty comprehensive list of IPv4 Options usage if you're worried about dropping or ignoring IPv4 Options.

I seem to remember you asking about hardening an internet router in the past.  It's usually very safe to *drop IP options on internet-facing routers*.

Comment: Yes I did, thanks for the answer. One more question. I guess that this ACL and command "Router(config)# ip options drop" have the same effect?

Comment: An ACL can be selectively applied.  That command is global.  Normally I jus configure ip options drop

Comment: @MikePennington Is it common to ignore the _contents_ of the packets IP options, rather that _drop_ the packets?

Comment: I can't speak about what is or isn't common for IPv4 Options handling.   I usually say drop IPv4 Options on internet-facing routers (due to the risk of DDoS against your internet-facing router's control plane).  FWIW, cisco has knobs to globally "drop" or "ignore" IPv4 Options.